# Cocoa pdf page object for search and copy/paste?

Tags: ios, macos, pdf

I know that a method for rendering pdf pages into images is available natively in quartz.
Now I need to know if there is an object-oriented way to have pdf pages in my application (OSX and iOS) which are "live", that is copy/paste is possible and search too.
In other words, is available in some way a ready-made object to put into a view? I mean natively, without commercial libraries, but for commercial application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple’s PDF Kit, introduced with Mac OS X version 10.4, lets you add PDF viewing and navigation to your Mac OS X application with just a few clicks in Interface Builder.

With PDF Kit, your application can access much of the functionality described in the Adobe PDF specification with just a small number of Cocoa classes. The Preview application in Mac OS X 10.4 and later uses PDF Kit for PDF support, so you can use that application as an example of some of PDF Kit’s features.

If you want to go beyond simple PDF viewing, PDF Kit includes a suite of Objective-C utility classes. These utility classes provide lower-level support of PDF features, allowing more control over annotations, selections, and so on.